# Revs go up when I depress clutch pedal

Tags: engine, mazda, tribute

As I was driving my 2001 Mazda Tribute today I was pulling up to a red light and I depressed the clutch pedal as I came to a stop. Once the clutch pedal was depressed the revs suddenly shot up to 3000rpm without any accelerator engaged. Since then it has happened whenever I do the same and the revs will not drop unless I engage the clutch in gear or I let the clutch pedal up upon which it will very slowly decrease in revs to the normal idle engine speed. As I am driving the car now feels like I have cruise control (it doesn't!) as the car will not naturally decelerate even though there is no accelerator engaged.

I thank you for any help you can give me in advance as if it is a simple fix it could save me a trip to the mechanic!

Cheers,

Comment: Possibly an air leak on the intake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Throttle body needs a serious cleaning. Gunk or some sort of residue is sticking your throttle at 3000 revs. Disconnect the rubber intake tube assembly and use a good quantity of throttle body cleaner and a couple of squirts of wd-40 to ensure the throttle mechanism itself is free and operating normally. Your vehicle being 2001 vintage I assume that it is not drive by wire like most if not all new models are now.

If it were a drive by wire system this would require a reprogramming of your engine computer in order to recalibrate all the various sensors and the idle speed etc.

One thing I would also reccommend is changing the rubber intake tube assembly (not sure if that is the exact technical name for that part) because after about 6 years of hot and cold cycles with numerous cycles flexing the rubber starts to deteriorate developing cracks in the rubber folds causing air leaks eventually triggering a check engine light.